# Different SecurityContraints for different Tomcat Connectors

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up 3 Tomcat Connectors for my SpringBoot application:

1. An SSL connector configured in application.yml
2. A redirect connector that redirects port 80 to whatever the secure connection is configured to
3. A normal http connector without redirecting or anything

These last 2 I'm configuring in a seperate config class as per [this tutorial](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/)
I did modify it slightly to configure the pure http connector though.

These last 2 are being difficult. Seperately they work fine, but when configuring them together I need to chose between having a security constraint which breaks the pure http connector, or no constraint which breaks the redirection.
Apparently Spring hates fun and won't let me have 2 factoriy beans :/

Is there any way to apply different SecurityConstraints to different Connectors?

I'll include my config class so you guys have an idea about what I have so far:

```
@Configuration
public class RedirectConfig {
    @Value("${server.alt-port}")
    private int altPort;
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint); //<-- I must add it for the entire factory or not at all
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateRedirectHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(altPort);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        return connector;
    }

    private Connector initiateRedirectHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(port);
        return connector;
    }
}
```